# Automate iOS memory leak detection with instrumentation in Terminal

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, bamboo, xcode-instruments

I have requirements where I need to automate detection of following in iOS project:

- Detection of memory leak
- Detection of abandoned or objects which grows without being released and causes app to crash

And all this should be done in terminal so I can use it in Bamboo.

Basically I have app which will run for long time(for example 24 hours). I can start it using **instruments** to launch up with memory leak template. But I am having hard time to figure out the way where I can parse it find out what other objects are leaking and growing without being released.

Just to summarise right now I launch instrumentation tool with leak profile manually stop the app and then manually going through the result to check if objects are not leaking so I want to automate it by running commands in terminal.

I will appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Instruments [can profile apps via terminal](https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/#/devb14ffaa5) and you can specify

- `-t` profiling template
- `-D` path where to store `.trace` file with measured output

For reading `.trace` files use [TraceUtility](https://github.com/Qusic/TraceUtility) which enables you to parse out useful information about some of instruments like: time profiler, allocations, connections and now also memory leaks.

For practical example check out [article](https://tech.showmax.com/2019/02/automated-mem-leak-testing-ios/) where we described how to automate whole pipeline that

1. run UI test
2. profile with Instruments
3. parse .trace files
4. determine new memory leaks